# Missing Dependencies/Packages on yum install

Tags: yum

I'm at my wit's end with this.

After a lengthy series of events I've been trying to install libreoffice on Centos 6.3 using yum

I've was successful in the past but after encountering some seg faults when using it with unoconv. I tried installing and uninstalling numerous other versions of both LibreOffice and OpenOffice.

No I'm trying to go back to my initial set up I'm presented with a long list of errors of the nature:

```
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-calc-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_cppuhelpergcc3.so.3(UDK_3.6)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-calc-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libreoffice-ure = 1:3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-calc-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_cppu.so.3(UDK_3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-core-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_salhelpergcc3.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-core-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_sal.so.3(UDK_3_0_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-base-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libjvmfwk.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-calc-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_sal.so.3(UDK_3.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-core-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_sal.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-core-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libuno_cppu.so.3(UDK_3.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:libreoffice-calc-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
```

I believe I deleted something I shouldn't have but I have no idea where to start.

Any help or advice on fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `yum repolist` to see what repos are active and put the output here.

Comment: Sounds like `libreoffice-ure-3.4.5.2-16.1.el6_3.x86_64.rpm` package is not installed.

Comment: `yum reinstall <packagelist>` should fix things.